# Stopping the spam from tribal vassals

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing as the King of Sweden in the Charlemagne start. I now have lots of tribal vassals. I'm also fighting a lot of wars.

The problem is that every time I start a war and call my 20+ vassals, I have to click through the popups of them accepting/refusing. Is there a way to disable this or, better still, only display the ones who refuse?

Answer (score 1):

When it pops out, stop the game, click a little "plus" icon on the bottom of the screen. Its on the left of your map, then its open channel log or how its called, click right(or left ? ;D dont remember) mouse button on right event(for example someone joined faction x) and there pop out a small window, there will be a option to change how this type of message pops up (small boxes to tick for specific option). I put it to show only in log, not in screen.

Comment: Doesn't work- my allies' responses to the call to arms aren't actually in the log.

Comment: @Studoku you can always pause and just hold enter to get through them all

Comment: Even if they all appeared at the same time, which they don't, enter doesn't skip them.

Comment: @Studoku Im sorry that is eu4 I forgot that they change the shortcuts in each game.

Comment: It's shift-click to close all of the same type in CK2.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie right, but that doesn't work for popups that pause the game (at least not for me on MacOS version - but enter does close a popup). If you have them in the high or low priority tab, you can dismiss all messages of the same type with a shift-click on the red X.

Comment: @Dacio That's right, and that's by design as far as I can tell. If a certain type of message is unimportant enough that you want to be able to dismiss them all at once, you should change them to a non-popup display, as the answer describes.